# Was birth of Dhristadhyumna due to an advanced Genetic experiment?

Tags: mahabharata

The king of Panchala, Drupada undertook a  sacrifice to please the gods and obtain offspring by their blessing. Drupada desired a son who could kill Guru  Drona, who had humiliated Drupada in battle and taken half his kingdom.  With the help of two saints ( **Yaja and Upayaja**), Drupada undertook the sacrifice.

> Excerpts from the English translation of Mahabharata by Kisiri Mohan Ganguli

And when everything was complete, Yaja, after having poured libations of clarified butter on the sacrificial fire, commanded Drupada's queen, saying,

> 'Come hither, O queen, O daughter-in-law of Prishata! A son and a daughter have arrived for thee!'
>
> Hearing this, the queen said, 'O Brahmana, my mouth is yet filled with saffron and other perfumed things. My body also beareth many sweet scents; I am hardly fit for accepting (the sanctified butter which is to give me offspring). Wait for me a little, O Yaja! Wait for that happy consummation.'
>
> Yaja, however, replied, 'O lady, whether thou comest or waitest, why should not the object of this sacrifice be accomplished when the oblation hath already been prepared by me and sanctified by Upayaja's invocations?'

Having said this, Yaja poured the sanctified libation on the fire, whereupon arose from those flames a child resembling a celestial who possessing the effulgence of fire, was terrible to behold. With a crown on this head and his body encased in excellent armour, sword in hand, and bearing a bow and arrows, he frequently sent forth loud roars.

---

If we look at this story in literal sense, we will understand that Yaja performed for the sake of Drupada an Yajna, with the help of his younger brother Upayaja.  And, when the queen of Drupada was not ready, he poured the sanctified oblation in to the fire, and Dhristadhyumna born out of fire.

My question is:

When I looked at this story in a rational way,  a thought occurred to me that the Yajna conducted by Yaja, was in fact an advanced Genetic experiment (blending test tube baby technology and Cloning Technology).

Yaja might have obtained the required cells from the body of Drupada and sought of cells of the queen to complete the advanced Genetic experiment.  And, when she was not ready, he might have adopted some other method and completed the task.

Can we think in that way?

Comment: Scientific speculation is not allowed on this site, because it leads to too much opinion-based discussion.  So I'm closing your question.

Comment: It is not scientific speculation.   I am trying to reason in scientific way.  It is up to you to decide.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, I feel that more the scientific nature of a question, lesser the opinions. Because in science the things have only 1 answer. :-) Nevertheless, in this question I don't see any speculation on science because it covers MahAbhArata event which cannot be off-topic. I believe even Kauravas were also born similarly. BTW, the actual question (last line) should be more sensible. Because it just asks Yes/No. :-) I don't have any answer of this. We have to just assume that it happened like that. Good part is that, due to Test tube technology we will not be too skeptic to such stories.

Comment: Yes, Mahabharatha can be related with scientific inventions/technologies, there so many other articles related like you have asked in here http://mahabharathascience.blogspot.in/p/weapons-of-mass-destruction.html http://www.bibliotecapleyades.net/arqueologia/esp_mohenjo_daro_1.htm

Comment: @iammilind what Keshav meant was it leads to speculation. The person who  answers this question might be Pro in advance genetic engineering but that scientific explanation is not mentioned in our scriptures. What if the birth of Dristadhyumna really involved more advanced genetic experiment which has yet to be discovered. No one can verify veracity of the answer.